# Template function overloading on basis of pointer type?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Can a template function be overloaded on basis of pointer type as below:

```
1)
template <class T>
void Function(T* ptr, char m)
{
    ...
}

2)
template <class T>
void Function(T i, char m)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it valid in C++?

Part 2:
Can i specialize(template specialization) Function on basis of pointer type as below(ignore the above overloading for this case)?

```
3)
template<>
inline  Function<string>(string sptr, char m)
{
    ...
}
```

PS: when i try to specialize template 1 with 3 I get compilation error.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it and it compiles fine but not sure whether such thing is legally valid as there are many cases which works fine on one compiler and doesn't work on another and comes under undefined category.

Comment: You *can* totally legally have `void f(int)`and `void f(int*)` side by side. It doesn't matter if these two overloads come from templates or are defined directly...

Comment: It is really impressive, how C++ can put fear in developers, so they don't trust compiler at all :)

Comment: @Inline The problem is that there are just too many examples out there the compiler lied. Often due to compiler extensions (e. g. accepting VLA in C++), sometimes even due to bugs. So, although a good idea to consult the compiler first, you only can be 100% if you have some reference to the standard...

Comment: Ah, I think I see where *you* see a problem: Actually, you can derive e. g. `void function(int*, char)` from both templates. Then which one to chose? Rule is simple: always the more specific one... Which one is the more specific one? Well, first one *requires* a pointer while second one could accept *anything*, thus first one is more specific. A bit sloppy wording, I know, but I think you still get the point...

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly legal to overload the templates based on the pointer type. When the same function template specialization matches more than one overloaded function template, *partial ordering* of overloaded function templates is performed to select the best match.

In this case it is done by [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) for a call to a function template specialization. For more info see [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Even your function template specialization is perfectly valid.

Quoting [cppreference's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Specifically, partial ordering takes place in the following situations:

1. [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) for a call to a function template specialization

```cpp
template<class X> void f(X a);
template<class X> void f(X* a);
int* p;
f(p);
```

2. When the [address of a function template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) is taken

```cpp
template<class X> void f(X a);
template<class X> void f(X* a);
void (*p)(int*) = &f;
```

3. When a [placement operator delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) that is a function template specialization is selected to match a placement operator new
4. when a [friend function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends), an [explicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation), or an explicit specialization refers to a function template specialization

```cpp
template<class X> void f(X a);  // first template f
template<class X> void f(X* a); // second template f
template<> void f<>(int *a) {} // explicit specialization
 // template argument deduction comes up with two candidates:
 // foo<int*>(int*) and f<int>(int*)
 // partial ordering selects f<int>(int*) as more specialized
```

Comment: That's not overloading, technically. class template partial specialization works differently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having these two templates is perfectly legal and they will overload each other just fine. The specialisation is also perfectly legal.